# How to set WebStorm sign "|" foreground color

Tags: webstorm

The closest I've found is:

File→Settings→Editor→Color Scheme→Language Defaults→Braces and Operators

But I didn't find the setting for the `|` symbol, which appears as a red.

Comment: please can you provide a code fragment where this operator is shown in red?

Comment: ![](https://i.loli.net/2018/04/16/5ad478660fbb8.jpg)

Comment: it's color can be changed in **File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | JavaScript | Operation**; but note tht changing will change colors of all other assignment operators (`=`, `^=`, etc.) as well

Comment: It can only change the color of "=",But "|" cannot be changed.

Comment: to me, it changes them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a webstorm problem,  but a Windows GDI(+) Anti aliasing bug.